# Can not resolve NullPointerException in WebClient Builder | Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-webclient

I am getting a Nullpointer Exception when calling a service with the help of WebClient.

Service

```
@Service
public class DummyWebclient  {

  @Autowired
  private WebClient getWebClient;

  public DummyWebclient() {}

  Response client3 = getWebClient.get().
            uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                .queryParam("param1", "value1")
                .queryParam("param2", "value2")
                .build() )
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Response.class)
            .block();

  public Response getClient3() {
        return client3;
    }
}
```

Template Webservice

```
@Component
public class GetWebClient {

    @Bean
    public WebClient GetWebclient() {
       return WebClient
               .builder()
               .baseUrl(MainURL.getMAINURL())
               .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
               .build()
                ;
    }
}
```

And a simple test to reveive the response throws NullPointer Exception, Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at (DummyWebclient.java:19)

Line `Response client3 = getWebClient.get().`

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
class DummyWebclientTest{

    @Autowired
    private DummyWebclient dummyWebclient;

    @Test
    public void GetResponse2() {
        Response response2 = dummyWebclient.getClient3();
        System.out.println(response2);
    }

}
```

**My question is: why does Spring does not create a Bean and insert to Service?**

Comment: SpringBoot, by default, scans for components inside the package where you kept your main class. EIther move the component file in the same package or use @ComponentScan and provide the packages to scan for components. Refer ->https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning

Answer (score 0):

You got the order of initialization wrong:

```
@Service
public class DummyWebclient  {

  @Autowired
  private WebClient getWebClient;

  public DummyWebclient() {}

  Response client3 = getWebClient.get().
            uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                .queryParam("param1", "value1")
                .queryParam("param2", "value2")
                .build() )
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Response.class)
            .block();

  public Response getClient3() {
        return client3;
    }
}
```

With your current code:

- new instance of DummyWebClient is created
- all fields are initialized to their default values

  - getWebClient to null
  - client3 initialization attempt: BOOM
- only after that Spring will attempt fields injection

You have 2 options to fix this:

**Option1**

Use constructor injection:

```
    private WebClient getWebClient;

    @Autowired
    public DummyWebClient(WebClient getWebClient) {
        this.getWebClient = getWebClient;
    }
```

this is good idea anyway

**Option 2**

You make a blocking HTTP call in field initialization.
Why not get Response on demand, in `getClient3()` call?

IMHO, you should apply both changes.

Comment: Actually the Response by itself was/is inside getClient3 method (and all other similar methods). And  
@Autowired
private WebClient getWebClient;
works brilliantly. The thing is, everything is working as you described in Option 2, but when extracting response from the method to constructor, I can not find good solution to force to create a bean.

Comment: In the code you posted, variable `client3` is NOT initialized in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to **Stackoverflow**

class `GetWebClient` should have `@Configuration` annotation instead of `@Component`

Comment: While this is not idiomatic, defining `@Bean` methods inside `@Component` actually works and is not the reason why this code fails